# The event clicking on node in d3.js in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp, jsf, d3.js

I am using `D3 Javascript` library in a `JSF` application. I am presenting a graph of nodes in a JSP page. What I am trying to do is when I click on one the nodes, I am expecting to send the id of that node to Managed Beans as a request and the Managed Beans class connects to the server to search for its children. The `D3 Javascript` code is in a `JSP` file. Here is my code:

```
.
.
<body>
<f:view>
node.enter().append("circle")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; })
  .attr("r", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.size) / 10 || 4.5; })
  .style("fill", color)
  .on("click", click)
  .call(force.drag);
  .
  . 
  function click(d) {
    // This is for clicking on a node and sending the id of the node to the Managed beans
      }
  update();
  }
  }
.
.
<body>
<f:view>
```

My question is: Normally, in `JSP`, you can do something similar to this code:

```
<h:inputText  value="#{managedBeans.bean}"></h:inputText>
<h:commandButton action="#{managedBeans.action_1}" value="value_X"></h:commandButton>
```

or something similar to this:

```
<button type="button" onclick="">Click me </button>
```

In case of clicking on one of nodes in a D3 graph, how can I send the id of the node (such as: name) to the Managed beans as a request? I do now know how to get that clicking event on the node in Javascript within JSP code. Your help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: If you know what object on the server to call, you could do that directly from within the `click` function.

Comment: Well. I need to send the id of that node by clicking on that node. I am having getter and setter methods in my Managed Beans class. I know how onclick event works in JSP but how can I do the same for d3.js?

Comment: You should be able to use the same code as you do in `onclick=""`.

Comment: If you use d3's `node.on(click, clickHandler)` to attach the event, your clickHandler function will be run with `this` set to the DOM element for the node that was clicked; you can therefore get the id as `this.id`, and pass it to your request function.

Comment: I will try this one and let you know soon. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With using node.on(click, clickHandler), everything should be done within Javascript and nothing to do with JSP tags in this case. Any idea?

Comment: One question, please. When I use onclick = "", I should send a request to the Managed beans class. Do I need to create a form to send the id of that node in order to get a response back from Managed beans in return? Could that be done using Ajax or XMLHttpRequest as I am using Javascript?

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea of onclick="". It is working now.